# Big O notation help, confused

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, complexity-theory, notation

I have this problem,  prove or disprove

```
F(n)=10n^3+3n
g(n)=5n^2
```

This is what I have tried and gotten

```
k=1
n>1
F(n)/g(n)=(10n^3+3n/5n^2)<(10n^3+3n^2/5n^2)=13/5
```

Thus

```
10n^3+3n<=13/5(5n^2)
10n^3+3n<=13n^2n when n>1
```

Is this correct?

Comment: What is the `t` in F(n), is that a `+`?

Comment: More importanto, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: include your problem description, what is expected, what you get,

Comment: Yes it is a + my apologies for the mistake and im trying to prove or disprove it

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal: You've given us definitions of two mathematical functions `F` and `g`.  What *statement* about `F` and `g` are you trying to (dis)prove?

Answer (score 0):

Given the condition, `n>1` and I don't get the necessity to calculate the value of k.

Also, F(n) > G(n) for all values of `n>1`.

Your steps seems incorrect at

```
for `n>1`, F(n)/g(n)=(10n^3+3n/5n^2) < (10n^3+3n^2/5n^2) = `10n+3`
// still dependent on n and as n>1, so the function is greater
```

So, the next step is also wrong.

```
10n^3+3n <= (10n+3) * (5n^2)  // correct it as per what I've mentioned
```

So, as `(5n^2)` multiplied with `(10n+3)` is greater than `10n^3+3n`; but, also `5n^2` is always lesser than `(10n^3+3n)` for all values of n>1.

At last step, your conclusion should be

```
10n^3+3n <= (10n+3) * (5n^2) when n>1
         <= (50n^3+15n^2) when n>1
```

At last, F(n) = 10n^3+3n     &&     G(n)=5n^2
              = O(n^3)       &&         =O(n^2)

And hence,`G(n) = O(F(n))`,but, reverse can't be true...

```
// as upper bound can be considered and inflated as much in powers of n
```